# Passing JS objects to an MVC Partial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have an observable that gets modified in the main view.  In a "Preview" below, I render an MVC partial (this preview is re-used in many places throughout the app) displaying some of that observable data in real-time as it gets updated.

When I call the partial:

```
@Html.Partial("_TitlePanel", Model)
```

How can I also pass a knockout / js object to the Partial?

Comment: Do you need specifically pass it? The object is available to the whole page regardless is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need "pass a knockout js" in your partial view. On the client side, no main and partial views, only one html page. So, you should add data-binding in your partial view, like as in main view.